# Exception when trying to change a composite primary key based JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to develop a REST API with Spring where users can basically register Comics and evaluate the registered Comics.

One of the API's features is precisely the user being able to give a rating to the Comics. To store the notes in the database I created a JPA entity based on a composite primary key (user, comic).

I also created a service that is used to register and change notes.

The problem is that: the first time a user registers a rating for a given comic, everything happens without any problem, but when the user tries to change the rating an exception occurs: "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Duplicate row was found and `ASSERT` was specified"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**RatePK**

```
@Embeddable
public class RatePK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="comic_id")
    private Comic comic;

    public RatePK(User user, Comic comic) {
        this.user = user;
        this.comic = comic;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Comic getComic() {
        return comic;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setComic(Comic comic) {
        this.comic = comic;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((comic == null) ? 0 : comic.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((user == null) ? 0 : user.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        RatePK other = (RatePK) obj;
        if (comic == null) {
            if (other.comic != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!comic.equals(other.comic))
            return false;
        if (user == null) {
            if (other.user != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!user.equals(other.user))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

**Rate**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_RATE")
public class Rate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private RatePK id = new RatePK();
    
    private Integer rate;

    public Rate(User user, Comic comic, Integer rate) {
        super();
        this.id.setUser(user);
        this.id.setComic(comic);
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public RatePK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setId(RatePK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setRate(Integer rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Rate other = (Rate) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

**RateRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface RateRepository extends JpaRepository<Rate, RatePK> {

}
```

**RateService**

```
public void save(Long comicId, RateNewDTO rateDto) {        
    UserSS userAuthenticated = UserService.authenticated(); 
        
    User user = userService.findById(userAuthenticated.getId());
        
    Comic comic = comicService.findById(comicId);
        
    Rate rate = new Rate(user, comic, rateDto.getRate());

    rateRepository.save(rate);  
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Duplicate row was found and `ASSERT` was specified
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3481) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3471) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromCacheOrDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:567) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:536) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:529) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithRegularProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1219) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1024) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.lambda$entityIsDetached$0(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.LoadQueryInfluencers.fromInternalFetchProfile(LoadQueryInfluencers.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:834) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy146.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:620) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy166.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.gustavo.comicreviewapi.services.RateService.save(RateService.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.gustavo.comicreviewapi.resources.ComicController.saveRate(ComicController.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at com.gustavo.comicreviewapi.resources.ComicController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.saveRate(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at com.gustavo.comicreviewapi.filters.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work.
Basically, what happens is:

1. You manually create an entity with the existing key and call save() method
2. JPA repo figures that it is existing entity based on the fact that ID is not null, so it tries to merge it
3. During merge it founds out that entity with the same key is already in the session (maybe in the cache after the 1st save, maybe it was loaded with the Comic entity), but the object you passed to the save() method is different (id is the same, but object is different). That is why you get into the method `entityIsDetached()`
4. It tries to get the corresponding entity from the session in order to merge it with the one you have provided. And then it cannot find it in the session for some reason and tries to load it from database. So, maybe it is some bug within hibernate, maybe there is some issue in the code, for example, something is wrong with `user or comic equals/hashcode methods`, you did not provide them to us. And this is a very likely reason why hibernate at some cases finds entity, at some - not.
   Because for me your example is working fine, I tested.

But to make it work for sure, if you want to update rate, you need to search for an existing one first, if found - update it, if not found - create a new one.
Like this

```
public void save(Long comicId, RateNewDTO rateDto) {        
UserSS userAuthenticated = UserService.authenticated(); 
    
User user = userService.findById(userAuthenticated.getId());
    
Comic comic = comicService.findById(comicId);
Optional<Rate> existingRate = rateRepository.findById(new RatePK(user, comic));
if (existingRate.isPresent()) {
  existingRate.setRate(rateDto.getRate());
  // if method is transactional, you may skip calling it: rateRepository.save(existingRate);  
  // exit
  return;
}   

// If rate was not found, create a new one
Rate rate = new Rate(user, comic, rateDto.getRate());
rateRepository.save(rate);
```

}

Comment: Hello Sve! I discovered that the problem was between a many-to-many relationship between two entities in my project (Comic and Author). I had it defined as `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`, and this cascade is generating the problem. Thanks for the help and tips!

Comment: You are welcome :) Glad you fixed it!